# directory access priveilege question

Tags: 12.04, permissions, directory, shared-folders

Let's say I get this as a result of ls -l:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 user user 0 Nov 19 20:13 file4
```

What does the 1 mean?

Im asking because I had 2 folders set up on my server working just fine, and they had the number 4 there, then I made a new folder, but it got the number 3 and doesn't work quite properly. How do I change this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd column (the number '1' in your case) is how many hard links point to that file or directory

> The second column is the number of links to the file i.e., (more or less) the number of names there are for the file. Generally an ordinary file will only have one link, but a directory will have more, because you can refer to it as '`dirname`' or '`dirname/.`' where the dot means 'current directory', and if it has a subdirectory named '`subdir`', you can also say '`dirname/subdir/..`' (the '`..`' means 'parent directory').

[source of the above](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~eva/unixinfo/ls.html), also see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/171946/251249)

Comment: So it shouldn't affect the sharing permissions at all?

Comment: @Icero Probably not, it's generally (very loosely) how many folders exist in that folder. A file should only ever have 1

Comment: Ahhh, that makes some sense.  I must have a different problem on my hands then.... If some one besides me creates a folder on the server, I can't delete or edit the name of it, which is becoming a problem.

Comment: @Icero Well, that's probably a permissions problem, try asking a new question (or searching the internet). Mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Comment: it solved a problem, and created more ;)

Comment: That's the way it works.